# How to cleanly change the style of a single element on click with a different color for each element of an ngFor with angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

i'm starting with angular and my question is quite simple. (I'm sure there is an answer on the internet but I don't know how to formulate my question simply)

[here is my component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dynoJ.png)

I just want to change the color of the button on the right side like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYRSR.png) and when i click on another one the first one get back to normal and [the actual change color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jezg1.png)

Here is the code of my component :

```
<div class="container-scrap">
<div class="legend">
    <div class="color-sample" [ngStyle]="{'background-color': scrap.color}"></div>
    <p>{{scrap.scrapName}}</p>
</div> 
<div>
    <button (click)="selectType($event, scrap.color)" class="legend-button" [disabled]="!availableInput"></button>
</div>
```

I'm calling my component this way :

```html
<app-scrap-list *ngFor="let scrap of scrapList" [scrap]="scrap" [availableInput]="availableInput"></app-scrap-list>
```

Currently i'm using only some simple javascript instruction
and the code of my `selectType($event, scrap.color)` is :

```
  selectType({target} : any, color : string): void {
    this.scrapListService.setSelected(this.scrap.id);

    //(document.querySelectorAll(".legend-button") as HTMLCollectionOf<HTMLElement>).forEach(btn => btn.style.backgroundColor = "white")
    const legendButton = Array.from(
      document.getElementsByClassName('legend-button') as HTMLCollectionOf<HTMLElement>
    );
    
    legendButton.forEach(btn => {
      btn.style.backgroundColor = 'whitesmoke';
      btn.style.borderColor = 'grey';
    });
    

    target.style.backgroundColor = color;
    target.style.borderColor = color;
    target.style.backgroundImage = "url(../../assets/ajout_rectangle_active.png)";
  }
```

Is there a better and simple way to do it using angular properties like ng-class, ng-style or others?

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks like have some old fashoned javascript.
For a better approch, maybe [Render2](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/angular-using-renderer2) could be more useful.
In short: Render2 is used to change style and other properties to a element.
You could create a custom component that defines the button.

Comment: While this answer may suits to OP's need, you should also see how do I write a good answer [answer], you should also provide some example code.